# Entity framework data contract

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to WCF and Entity framework.

I have a class library "A" which contains `DatabaseEntities.edmx` (Entity Framework `objectContext`).

This library is exposing a class "B" which contains a function `FunctionB`, internally using the entity objects.

I have taken this library "A" reference into a WCF web service and inside the `IService.cs` - I have coded it like this:

```
[OperationContract]
void FunctionB_Proxy();
```

Without defining any `DataContract` I have gone into `Service1.cs` and implemented this function
as below:

```
public void FunctionB_Proxy()
{
  ClassB x=new ClassB();//Class of ClassLibrary
  x.FunctionB(); 
}
```

This works fine.

But my question: is `DataContract` optional in WCF?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 10):

As of **.NET 3.5 SP1** - yes, the `[DataContract]` is no longer required.

If you omit it, then the class will be serialized like the XML serializer does: all public properties on your class will be serialized by default.

However: if you start using a `[DataContract]` on your class or a `[DataMember]` on one of your properties, then you **must** decorate all properties you want to serialize with a `[DataMember]`.

So it's either : leave out those attributes entirely (use the default behaviour like the XML serializer uses), or then be specific and decorate the class with `[DataContract]` and every property you want to have serialized with `[DataMember]`. I prefer this second approach.

Comment: Looks very impressive,thanks for such a valuable answer. I also would have preferred your suggested route, however to do so i would have to write code myself for ORM.