# C# Rest API return dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, webmethod, webservicehost

I have an webservice

```
WebServiceHost webServiceHost= new WebServiceHost(typeof(WebMethods), new Uri(url));
webServiceHost.Open();

public class Fish { public string name = "I am a fish"; }
public class Dog { public int legs = 4; }
public class Cat { public DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;}
```

One of my webMethods should return a dynamic object

WebMethod:

Solution 1

```
[OperationBehavior]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/isTest?class={cl}")]
object isTest(string cl)
{
    object obj;

    switch (cl)
    {
        case "fish":
            obj= new Fish();
            break;
        case "dog":
            obj= new Dog();
            break;
        default:
            obj= new Cat();
            break;

    }
    return obj;

}
```

Solution 2

```
[OperationBehavior]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/isTest?class={cl}")]
dynamic isTest(string cl)
{
    dynamic obj;

    switch (cl)
    {
        case "fish":
            obj= new Fish();
            break;
        case "dog":
            obj= new Dog();
            break;
        default:
            obj= new Cat();
            break;

    }
    return obj;
}
```

Both are not working. The response is ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Any idea how to realise it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on 'return obj'. Is the appropriate object returned?

Comment: Yes the appropriated object is returned!

Comment: Type in the full url (http://localhost:8323/somewebservice/isTest?class=fish) in a web browser and give the full error msg. if you are using IE try pressing F11 (I think) and watch your network responses

Comment: In the Networktab i just get the information that the result is aborted... My other webMethod /running returns true.. So i have no connection problems.

Comment: Maybe you should specify `[DataContract]` attribute to your returning class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170160/wcf-entity-framework-err-connection-reset

Comment: tested. But same response

Comment: Exactly.  Run the web service in Chrome, hit F12 to view Developer Options, and open the Network tab.  We'd need to see exactly what your service is returning, eg : http://i.stack.imgur.com/OhVNw.png   Btw, I was having this issue when a database exception occurred which contained a line-break in it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006976/wcf-web-services-returning-an-error-exception-string

Comment: [Exception picture](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-30107671/fail.png.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a JSON string.
Add the following to your uses:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

and the following in your body

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

change your return type to `string` instead of `object`

Comment: OP has already used `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`. It is expected that the WCF do the translation.

Comment: I need to return an object. Returning a string is not a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the "HttpResponseMessage" response or you can just send the model object in create response  method.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage isTest(int id)
{
   Model model = Model.table.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
   if (model != null)
   {
      //return Request.CreateResponse<Model>(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
      //or
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
   }
   else
   {
      return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Model Not Found");
   }
}
```